# Tagulous - Getting AutoComplete Fields to work

Tags: python, django, autocomplete

I have installed Tagulous successfully in to my Django app, and I have created a Tag textfield although, I'm struggling to get the AutoComplete process to work. I have been referencing the Tagulous instructions.

I have installed AutoComplete and have included the relevant JS and CSS libraries within my Settings.py. Along with ensuring that `'dal'` and `'dal_select2'` is installed under INSTALLED_APPS.

When I go to my form, I'm not receiving any errors and the Skills tag field appears. Although, there is no sign of any autocompletion working, the field just currently behaves as a regular tag field without the autocomplete feature.

Here's my code so far:

Views.py - (I have imported `from dal import autocomplete` in to this file)

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
   
    model = Post
    fields = ['content', 'image', 'skills']
    widgets = {
            'skills': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='skills-autocomplete')
        }
    template_name = 'sfsrv/post_new.html'
    success_url = '/'
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        data['tag_line'] = 'Create new post'
        return data

class SkillsAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        # Don't forget to filter out results depending on the visitor !
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return Skills.objects.none()

        qs = Skills.objects.all()

        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)

        return qs
```

URLs.py (I have imported `from sfsrv.views import SkillsAutocomplete` in to this file.

```
    url(
        'skills-autocomplete/$',
        SkillsAutocomplete.as_view(),
        name='skills-autocomplete',
    ),
```

Models.py (I have imported both `tagulous.models`
and `from dal import autocomplete` in to this file

````
class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='srv_media')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    skills = tagulous.models.TagField()
    tags_store = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content[:5]
```
Any assistance would be really appreciated as I'm new to Tagulous in Django! :-)
````

Comment: Author of Tagulous here - I haven't tested it with that library. Tagulous comes with its own select2-based autocomplete, so perhaps use that? https://radiac.net/projects/django-tagulous/documentation/usage/#example_autocomplete_views

Comment: After following your suggestion, I have removed the DAL Select2 import and I have now got the Tagulous Select/TagFields working in the Django Admin interface which is brilliant. Although, I'm struggling to get the JS and CSS for Tagulous to import in the frontend. I have included the relevant Tagulous Autocomplete JS and CSS settings within settings.py and I have also registered the autocomplete view. (Although, I have checked to see if the CSS/JS has been loaded, but i can't see any signs of the files being loaded in to my app) - Do you have any other suggestions regarding this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

check if you are using bootstrap 5 and practicing with jquery codes it conflicts with tagulous auto complete
Because Bootstrap 5 has dropped the support for jquery.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).